# Scraping a list of events from Wikipedia

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am using BS4 to scrape the wiki page for monthly events
The data I am looking for is not stored in a table but rather in a list.
How do I parse, clean it and turn it into a table?

This is what I've tried

```
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events/October_2019"

html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())

all_events=soup.find_all("li")

all_events

pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)

tableofevents = pd.DataFrame(all_events)

tableofevents
```

Which currently isnt working...
Any tips or tricks appreciated thank you.

R

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_site = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Current_events/October_2019"
response = requests.get(base_site)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all('a')
empty = []
for i in links:
  try:
    empty.append(i['href'])
  except:
    print('link not found')
import pandas as pd
table = pd.DataFrame(empty)
print(table)
```

Check this colab notebook:
[Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/14AFeCCpvtSS7AECNsOVMr7BuccuYLjzt?usp=sharing)